# logout script to kickoff the user from one system/location if he tries to login with the same username from other location

Tags: php, session

I am stuck at a point writing a script to kickoff(logout) the user from one system/location if he tries to login with the same username from other location. I have been using the IP addresses before, but this wont work because the user may login from same IP, same system but from different browser. any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

You could store the sessionid of the current login in a database when the user logs in, then check the current session id against the one of the database on requests, if it does not match, redirect to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misread your question.  You're going to need to rely on storing your sessions on a database.  CodeIgniter can do this for you automatically if you specify it in your config.php file.

Your script will need to query the database for any stored sessions which include the requested username.  If it finds one it means they're logged in on multiple computers, allowing you to delete the database session and initiate a new one so long as their login is authenticated.

Comment: How is the web app supposed to forcefully delete the cookie from the other browser?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thanks - I misread the question. Answer updated